# How to fix problems with android support libraries when changing compileSDK version?

Tags: android, build

I changed my app's compile SDK version and minimum SDK verion from 23 to 19 in order to support Kitkat.

The problem is in my build.gradle file I have the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

I am getting the error that these support libraries should not use a different SDK version from the compile SDK version.

Can I just change the `23.1.1` to `19.1.1` or would that cause potential build problems?

EDIT:

I have been reading some more articles and they say I should always set my compileSDK version to the latest version. However from what I understand, that could potentially lead me to use features that are only supported in the latest SDK version and not in the minimumSDK version of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the major number of the support library should always match the `compileSdkVersion`, you don't need to change the `compileSdkVersion` to support KitKat, and I would recommend against that.

Android development has moved on in the 3 years since the release of KitKat. To be able to make modern Material apps you need to use a recent version of the SDK. For example the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for SKD 19 doesn't have the Design or RecyclerView libraries.

To make sure that you support API 19, use the support library version of a class when you can and be cognizant of the API level of methods before you use them.

While setting `minSdkVersion` to 19 will cause the compile to not give you errors if you use a method not support on API level 19, lint will warn you when you do that. It will raise a NewApi eror for calling new methods not supported by all versions that your app targets.

You can run [lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) manually via `gradlew lint` or you can [configure](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) lint to run whenever a release or even a debug build is created. Setting `abortOnError true` while cause a build error that has a similar effect to a compile error.

Comment: If I set the minimum  API level to 19 will the compiler tell me if I use an API method that is above level 19?

Comment: @Roymunson I expanded my answer to address your comment.